# Async and await may be elided?

Tags: c#, async-await, resharper

I have this simple code :

```
 public async  Task<string> GetAsync()
   {
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("...");
   }
```

However Resharper says :

[image]

This warning is gone when I use a variable  :

```
 public async  Task<string> GetAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var st = await  httpClient.GetStringAsync("...");
            return st;
        }
```

I already know the danger when doing

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
 return  httpClient.GetStringAsync("...");
```

(Task will be canceled)

But that's not my case here since I'm using `await` ( and not using `using`).

**Question:**

Why does Resharper warn me?

Comment: Relevant: [Stephen Cleary article on task elision](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) and its subtle behavioral differences.

Comment: @JohnWu I read it. That's where I read about the `using` sample

Comment: Probably you are using an old version of Resharper/Visual Studio. Because it doesn't give any warning in my case. VS 2019.

Comment: @SalahAkbari https://i.imgur.com/7Wun4PQ.jpg , but now that you're saying it , I think I also have [async extension for resharper](https://github.com/BigBabay/AsyncConverter)

Comment: Resharper is telling you that you don't need to `await` there because you do nothing after it. There is a slight performance gain in cases like that.

Comment: Resharper is right in this case. What did Resharper say when you use the using block and return await ...?

Comment: @SirRufo It says nothing https://i.imgur.com/cmDNnmS.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir then that is your solution on this. You should dispose an IDisposable when you do not need it anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method "can" be rewritten as follows:

```
public Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    return httpClient.GetStringAsync("...");
}
```

thus avoiding the overhead of compiling an `async` method and then doing a costly control flow switch with `await`. The functionality is still the same. That's what R# is telling you about - you can omit the `async/await` and avoid an unnecessary overhead.

However, I put the "can" in quotes, as your code is smelly, because first of all, `HttpClient` is an `IDisposable`, so you should dispose of it after usage. Then the `async/await` will be necessary:

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("...");
    }
}
```

since this will be translated into an equivalent of

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("...");
    httpClient.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

This one you absolutely should fix. Secondly, a thing to consider is that creating `HttpClient`s can silently destabilise your app, as `HttpClient`s should be reused. See [this blog post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [this SE Stack Exchange post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests).